# How to make a campus gps

Tags: android, google-maps, path-finding

I'm with a group trying to make a campus GPS on android(and later other mobile devices), we got a lot of grunt work done. Through tedious code I'm sure we could make our own path finding class by taking a map and overlaying way points and lines and nodes, etc. But i feel there has to be a way to do this with software already out there.

I want to know is there a way to take Google maps, define way points and paths, and have it auto-calculate routes? The reason i want it badly to work through Google maps, is that Google maps is very easily re-sizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Maps JavaScript API V3, Directions Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/directions.html)